# Some attributes of model saving but others not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an an answer model and the query portion of it is saved, however, the anonymous portion of it is not.

This is my answers model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :question
    attr_accessible :anonymous, :answer, :commenter, :votes, :comments_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

And this is my form.

```
 <%= form_for([@question, @answer]) do |f| %>
        <p>
            <%= f.label :answer %>
            <%= f.text_area :answer, :cols => "50", :rows => "30"%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= check_box_tag(:anonymous)%>
            <%= label_tag(:anonymous, "Anonymous")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= f.submit "Submit Answer" %>
        </p>
  <% end %>
```

When I check my command prompt for the POST request, initially both answer and anonymous have values, answer may have string "aw;oeigh;aioewhg" and anonymous has value 1. However, when it does the actual create, anonymous gets nil and answer gets "a;oewigh;oih." Why is this

This is my controller if it's any help. Thanks!

```
def create
        @answer = @question.answers.new(params[:answer])
        if @answer.anonymous == true
            @answer.commenter = "Anonymous"
        else
            @answer.commenter = current_user.username
        end
        if @answer.save
            redirect_to question_path(@question)
        else
            redirect_to questions_path
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be because your params anonymous is not within answer

try

```
f.check_box :anonymous
```

instead

```
<%= check_box_tag(:anonymous)%>
```

Comment: <%=f.input :anonymous, as: :boolean%> results in undefined method f.input

Comment: Hmm same issue. The POST request definitely sends an anonymous => 1, however, when it's saving, it saves anonymous as nil.

Comment: Has to be in reverse     <%= label_tag(:anonymous, "Anonymous")%>
  <%= f.check_box :anonymous%>

Comment: nice ... enjoy coding :)